# Why does Hibernate put inner join in the case of one-to-one relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:
`UnsubscribedPartner` for unsubscribed from mailing partners

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mailing", name = "unsubscribed_partner")
public class UnsubscribedPartner {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "partner_id")
    private int partnerId;

    @Column(name = "unsubscription_date")
    private Date date;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Partner.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "partner_id")
    private Partner partner;

    //GET, SET
}
```

`Partner` partner's class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "partner", name = "partner")
public class Partner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "partner")
    private UnsubscribedPartner unsubscribedPartner;

    //GET, SET
}
```

I constructed the following criteria query:

```
String email;
//...
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Partner.class);
if(!(email == null)){
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
}
Criteria unsubscribedCrieria = criteria.createCriteria("unsubscribedPartner", "unsbcr");
unsubscribedCrieria.add(Restrictions.isNull("unsbcr.reason"));
```

But the result SQL query is

```
    select
        count(*) as y0_ 
    from
        partner.partner this_ 
    inner join
        mailing.unsubscribed_partner unsbcr1_ 
            on this_.id=unsbcr1_.partner_id 
    where
        unsbcr1_.unsubscription_reason_id is null
```

Inner join is not appropriate here, because the `unsubscribed_partner` tables may not any partner from the `partner` table, therefore I need `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createCriteria(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) states that `createCriteria(String, String)` is *functionally equivalent to* `createCriteria(String, String, int)` *using* `CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN for the joinType`.

So, try with `createCriteria("unsubscribedPartner", "unsbcr", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)` instead.